# ImportError: cannot import name 'load_img' from 'keras.preprocessing'

Tags: python, keras

I have a problem, every time I run this code:

```
from keras.preprocessing import load_img, save_img, img_to_array

from keras.preprocessing import image

plt.imshow(image.load_img('.....'))
```

I get the following error:
`cannot import name 'load_img' from keras.preprocessing`

I don't know how to fix it. I need `keras.preprocessing` to import `load_img`, `save_img` and `img_to_array`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/), `load_img` is a function that can be called from `image`, not imported. So remove the first line of imports. Use them like this instead:

```
from keras.preprocessing import image
plt.imshow(image.load_img('.....')) 

image.img_to_array(img, data_format=None, dtype=None)
```

And save_img belongs to the util package that can be called like this:

```
tf.keras.utils.save_img(
    path, x, data_format=None, file_format=None, scale=True, **kwargs
)
```